# length of json upto specific key

Tags: javascript, json

Lets say this is my variable, which I created by .serializeArray()

```
 a={"acctType1":"individual","compare_act1":"contains","match_name_act1":"accountName","text_act1":"","acctType2":"individual","compare_act2":"contains","match_name_act2":"accountName","text_act2":"","transType1":"401kContribution","compare_trans1":"contains","match_name_trans1":"description","text_trans1":"","transType2":"401kContribution","compare_trans2":"contains","match_name_trans2":"description","text_trans2":""}
```

so the length of this is = 16.

using :

> Object.keys(a).length;

Say I want to know the length only upto `transtype1` which should be 8 in this case how do I find that.

another example :

```
b={"acctType1":"individual","compare_act1":"contains","match_name_act1":"accountName","text_act1":"","acctType2":"individual","compare_act2":"contains","match_name_act2":"accountName","text_act2":"","acctType3":"individual","compare_act3":"contains","match_name_act3":"accountName","text_act3":"","acctType4":"individual","compare_act4":"contains","match_name_act4":"accountName","text_act4":"","acctType5":"individual","compare_act5":"contains","match_name_act5":"accountName","text_act5":"","transType1":"401kContribution","compare_trans1":"contains","match_name_trans1":"description","text_trans1":"","transType2":"401kContribution","compare_trans2":"contains","match_name_trans2":"description","text_trans2":"","transType3":"401kContribution","compare_trans3":"contains","match_name_trans3":"description","text_trans3":""}
```

length of b = 32

but length upto `transtype1` is 20

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Objects have no intrinsic order, so properties in them do not have a numerical position.

You could use a `for in` loop and count until you found the item you were looking for, but there would be no guarantee that the result you got would be consistent with the source order, the order from a previous loop around the object, or anything else.

Comment: I need to iterate over this object , but wanted to iterate over acctType and transType differently how do I achieve it then.?

Comment: Use arrays instead of repeating key names with different numbers on the end.

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin has said, you can't be sure that looping with  for in will give you the right order of keys in the object, and you should probably store your data in some other way. If you still want to do it though, you can do this:

```
function lengthUpTo(obj,key){
    var count=0;
    for(var i in obj){
        if(i==key) return count;
        count++
    }
    return -1;
}
console.log(lengthUpTo(b,"transType1"))//20
console.log(lengthUpTo(b,"nonExistant"))//-1
```